# How to get rid of burned oil smell from microwave?

Tags: microwave-oven, smoke

A few days ago, I made a blunder cooking popcorn and left the pot on the stove to burn the canola oil to a nice black paste. Smoke everywhere, and it took most of an hour to air it out. Smelled awful.

Now the microwave, directly above the stove, has a smell. It's most noticeable when the microwave is running. I've replaced the filter, but I think it must have gotten well beyond that.

Will it go away eventually? If not, is there something we can do to clean it (we've cleaned the surface already)? Trying to avoid a permanent smell and replacing a microwave if possible here.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly try storing a dish of baking soda in the microwave other than when you are using it as a simple deodorizer. Can't swear it will fix that level of problem, but it should help some, at least, and it's inexpensive.